# chat popup is not enabling alternatively in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a chat box in my application. So if a user "X" sends a message to user "Y", then the chat box in the bottom should open automatically for user "Y".

I have added 
$("#chatbox-content").show();

after sending a message, but it is applying for me i.e("X") but not for other user "Y"

```
<div id="chatbox-content" class="chatbox_content" style="display: <? if ( $ACCOUNT->get_option('chatState') == 'opened' ) echo 'block'; else echo 'none';?>;">
```

//Some html

### receiver

```
for ( var chat_line in history )
    {
        var account     = history[chat_line]['username'];
        var timestamp   = history[chat_line]['timestamp'];
        var message     = history[chat_line]['message'];
        var contenttype = history[chat_line]['content_type'];
        if ( contenttype == 'text' )
            history_html    += "<p><B>" + account + "</B>: " + message + "</p>";

        if ( contenttype == 'file' )
            history_html    += "<p><B>" + account + " uploaded</B>: <a target=_blank href='data/" + message + "'>"+message.substring(message.length-30)+"</a></p>";

    }
    //
    $("#chat-history").html( history_html );
    $("#chat-session").show();
```

### js file

$.post( "chat.php", { action: "send_message", message: msg }, function (data)
    { var chatState='opened'; $("#chatbox-content").show(); renderChat(data); });

Please help me.

Comment: How are you sending the messages? sockets.io? What server are you using? What triggers your `$(#chatbox-content").show();`? Basically we need to see some code to be able to help at all.

Comment: Ok, so X sends the message to the server, how is the server passing the message to Y? The `.show()` needs to happen in Y's callback for receiving such a message.

Comment: This is the receiver code